# How to read a CSV file that includes vectors of different lengths separated by commas?

Tags: r, csv

Say you have a CSV file. Each row of the file has numbers, vectors, and dates. Elements of each vector separated by semi-colons. For example a vector y in this csv file looks like ";1;2;4;7;2". The vectors are different lengths. I couldn't read this file using

```
read.table()
```

or

```
read.csv()
```

even with trying some things similar to what was written here [How to read a .csv file containing apostrophes into R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620155/how-to-read-a-csv-file-containing-apostrophes-into-r). Below is a simplified version of what 3 lines in the CSV file might look like

```
1,6,;2;3.1;45;31.2;3,2,;1;1;1;1;1;5,10/22/1938 1:25
2,5,;1;22;12;1.4;66,7,;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;6;9,11/25/1938 1:25
3,1,;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9,3.2,;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;9;10;11,11/25/1958 1:25
```

and here it is with spaces between the commas, to make it a bit more readable

```
1, 6, ;2;3.1;45;31.2;3, 2, ;1;1;1;1;1;5, 10/22/1938 1:25
2, 5, ;1;22;12;1.4;66, 7, ;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;6;9, 11/25/1938 1:25
3, 1, ;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9, 3.2, ;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;9;10;11, 11/25/1958 1:25
```

Each line has the same number of ','s, the only major difference between lines is that the vectors can be different. Note sometimes fields may be blank. I think it makes most sense for the output to be in the form of a list of a list. I was thinking of writing my own function that would effectively look something like (I'm not so proficient with lists yet so my language may be way off here)

```
data <- empty list of a list
while (we haven't reached the end of the file){ #don't know the function to do this
  temp = get first line of file #don't know the function to do this
  if temp is not empty{ #don't know the function to do this
    indices = which(temp==',')
    indices.col = which(temp==';')
    put temp[1:(indices(1)-1)] in the (counter,1) location of data;
    put temp[(indices(1)+1):(indices(2)-1)] in the (counter,2) location of data; 
    store the vector and deal with the colons somehow in (counter,3) location of data;
  }
}
```

Would there be an easier way to do this, maybe using read.table in a way that I missed. I'm not set on using lists of lists to do this. I want to basically do some regression analysis of the form y=mx+b, where x is one of the numerical entries and y is the scalar output of a function applied to one of the vector entries (eg sum(vector) = a*first entry of row + b). So perhaps keep that in mind. Also note that there would be an option to have this file use some other character besides semi colons to separate the vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still not knowing exactly what you are looking for, here's a suggestion.

Starting with DF from G. Grothendieck's answer:

```
### Optional cleanup to remove the leading semicolon.
### Not doing so will result in a couple of empty columns.
DF$V3 <- gsub("^;", "", DF$V3)
DF$V5 <- gsub("^;", "", DF$V5)
```

I would suggest `concat.split.multiple` from my "splitstackshape" package because (1) you can split multiple columns at once; (2) each column can have a different delimiter; and (3) you have the option of a "wide" or a "long" presentation of the split data. The long form can be further manipulated with tools like `melt` and `dcast` from the "reshape2" package giving you a lot of flexibility to do other stuff later on.

```
library(splitstackshape)
concat.split.multiple(DF, c("V3", "V5"), ";")
#   V1 V2  V4              V6 V3_1 V3_2 V3_3 V3_4 V3_5 V3_6 V3_7 V3_8 V3_9 V5_1
# 1  1  6 2.0 10/22/1938 1:25    2  3.1   45 31.2    3   NA   NA   NA   NA    1
# 2  2  5 7.0 11/25/1938 1:25    1 22.0   12  1.4   66   NA   NA   NA   NA    2
# 3  3  1 3.2 11/25/1958 1:25    1  2.0    3  4.0    5    6    7    8    9    1
#   V5_2 V5_3 V5_4 V5_5 V5_6 V5_7 V5_8 V5_9 V5_10
# 1    1    1    1    1    5   NA   NA   NA    NA
# 2    3    4    5    6    7    8    6    9    NA
# 3    2    3    4    5    6    7    9   10    11
out <- concat.split.multiple(DF, c("V3", "V5"), ";", "long")

head(out)
#   V1 V2  V4              V6 time V3 V5
# 1  1  6 2.0 10/22/1938 1:25    1  2  1
# 2  2  5 7.0 11/25/1938 1:25    1  1  2
# 3  3  1 3.2 11/25/1958 1:25    1  1  1
# 4  1  6 2.0 10/22/1938 1:25    2 NA NA
# 5  2  5 7.0 11/25/1938 1:25    2 NA NA
# 6  3  1 3.2 11/25/1958 1:25    2 NA 11
```

Answer (score 1):

Read it in using `read.csv`.  Columns 3 and 5 can then be re-read creating a matrix for each and replacing their columns with those matrices, i.e. column 3 becomes a matrix and so does column 5 as shown by the `str` output at the end:

```
Lines <- "1,6,;2;3.1;45;31.2;3,2,;1;1;1;1;1;5,10/22/1938 1:25
2,5,;1;22;12;1.4;66,7,;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;6;9,11/25/1938 1:25
3,1,;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9,3.2,;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;9;10;11,11/25/1958 1:25
"

DF <- read.csv(text = Lines, header = FALSE, as.is = TRUE)
DF2 <- transform(DF,
       V3 = as.matrix(read.table(text = V3, sep = ";", fill = TRUE)),
       V5 = as.matrix(read.table(text = V5, sep = ";", fill = TRUE))
    )
```

`str` output.  Note that each of columns 3 and 5 are themselves a matrix:

```
> str(DF2)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ V1: int  1 2 3
 $ V2: int  6 5 1
 $ V3: num [1:3, 1:10] NA NA NA 2 1 1 3.1 22 2 45 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : chr  "V1" "V2" "V3" "V4" ...
 $ V4: num  2 7 3.2
 $ V5: int [1:3, 1:11] NA NA NA 1 2 1 1 3 2 1 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : chr  "V1" "V2" "V3" "V4" ...
 $ V6: chr  "10/22/1938 1:25" "11/25/1938 1:25" "11/25/1958 1:25"
```

Also note that if you want to flatten it try:

```
 DF.flat <- do.call(data.frame, DF2)
```

ADDED:  How to flatten.